# XPath parsing excluding the tags and store in key value pair

Tags: xml, xpath, influxdb, telegraf

I am using telegraf to parse the snippet of XML using the XPath but I am not able to get the proper result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <report>
         <sampleduration>900</sampleduration>
         <network>
            <gateway>
              <red><element>103</element></red>
              <blue><element>105</element></blue>
              <black><element>120</element></black>
            </gateway>
          </network>
      </report>
```

Now I want the result as `red = 103,blue = 105,black = 120` but I am not able to get it.

This is just a very small snippet I have thousand of lines so I can't give the exact name to get the result.

I tried to generate the XPath for the above and got the below result but it's not what I expect.

```
/report
/report/network
/report/network/gateway
/report/network/gateway/black
/report/network/gateway/black/element
/report/network/gateway/blue
/report/network/gateway/blue/element
/report/network/gateway/red
/report/network/gateway/red/element
/report/sampleduration
```

If I pass above XPath telegraf don't give proper output. We are not sure which XPath to pass.

Comment: Will the gateway element always have the three children red, blue, and black, or can it have any number of children with different names?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.0,

```
string-join(//gateway/* ! (name() || '=' || .), ",")
```

In XPath 1.0 I don't think it can be done for the general case where gateway can have any number of children with arbitrary names, though it's easy enough for the case where you know it has exactly three children, especially if you know what their names are:

```
concat('red = ', //gateway/red, 
       ', blue = ', //gateway/blue, 
       ...)
```